# remove/update referencing value from the document node js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two models Connection and Customer. The customer is referenced in Connection. I want to delete the customer from the customer document  and remove or update the customer reference from the connection

the customer model is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

    const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', {
        cusName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        },
        nic: {
            type: String,
            default: false
        },
        cNumber: {
            type: String,
            default: true
        },
        cBranch: {
            type: String,
            default: true
        },
        cAddress: {
            type: String,
            default: true
        },
        cEmail: {
            type: String,
            default: true
        },
    })
    
    module.exports = Customer
```

and  Connection model is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', {
    cusName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    nic: {
        type: String,
        default: false
    },
    cNumber: {
        type: String,
        default: true
    },
    cBranch: {
        type: String,
        default: true
    },
    cAddress: {
        type: String,
        default: true
    },
    cEmail: {
        type: String,
        default: true
    },
})

module.exports = Customer
```

connection is again referenced by payment model
currunly implemented delete operation as follows.

```
router.delete('/customer/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const customer = await Customer.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)

        if (!customer) {
         
            return res.status(404).send()

            


        }

        res.send(customer)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly add a customer Id field in connection

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', {
    ...
    cusId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    ...
})

module.exports = Customer
```

and secondly, delete and the customers which have the same cusId

```js
router.delete('/customer/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const customer = await Customer.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
        const connection = await Connection.deleteMany({ cusId: req.params.id })
        if (!customer) {
            return res.status(404).send()

        }

        res.send({  message: "User has been deleted" })
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```